# Algolia Places API: How to get the street of a place?

Tags: algolia

We are evaluation algolia places API and want to use it to find the address of sights. As an example, we want to find "Reichstagsgebäude, Berlin" which works and we get the correct response:

```
    {
  "query": "Reichstag, Berlin",
  "suggestion": {
    "name": "Reichstagsgebäude",
    "administrative": "Berlin",
    "city": "Berlin",
    "country": "Deutschland",
    "countryCode": "de",
    "type": "address",
    "latlng": {
      "lat": 52.5186,
      "lng": 13.3761
    },
    "postcode": "10557",
    "highlight": {
      "name": "Reichstagsgebäude",
      "city": "<em>Berlin</em>",
      "administrative": "<em>Berlin</em>",
      "country": "Deutschland"
    },
    "value": "Reichstagsgebäude, Berlin, Berlin, Deutschland"
  }
}
```

But how to get the real address of the Building with the Street name and Street Number included, which should be "Platz der Republik 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Algolia Places has street-level precision. We currently only have data for house-level precision (i.e., street name and street number) for France.  This is an area we are actively looking to improve, but the data is still in process.